# Display values of the same array on the next line in ascending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm practicing PHP and I can't seem to get this in ascending order.

```
<?php
$cities=array (
  "Tokyo",
  "Mexico City",
  "New York City",
  "Mumbai",
  "Seoul",
  "Shanghai",
  "Lagos",
  "Buenos Aires",
  "Cairo",
  "London" 
  );

foreach($cities as $c){
  echo "$c, ";
}

sort ($cities);

foreach($cities as $c){
  echo "$c\n";
}
?>
```

This is what it shows after I run it:

Tokyo, Mexico City, New York City, Mumbai, Seoul, Shanghai, Lagos, Buenos Aires, Cairo, London, Buenos Aires Cairo Lagos London Mexico City Mumbai New York City Seoul Shanghai Tokyo

Comment: It is `rsort()`

Comment: you should visit this link before [link](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: rsort is descending. I'm trying to make it ascend from top to bottom on the new line

Comment: And what is the problem then?

Comment: use asort() function.. read manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: And what? `Buenos Aires` is __one element__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sorts just fine, the only problem are new lines. For new lines to be preserver `\n` you need to put your data in `<pre>` tag. I suggest using `<br>` though.

If you are running it in console `\n` works fine and your code works. You display cities once before sorting and once after sorting so I guess that's where your confusion came from.

```
<?php
$cities = array (
  "Tokyo",
  "Mexico City",
  "New York City",
  "Mumbai",
  "Seoul",
  "Shanghai",
  "Lagos",
  "Buenos Aires",
  "Cairo",
  "London" 
);

sort ($cities);

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($cities as $c) {
  echo "$c\n";
}
echo "</pre>";

foreach ($cities as $c) {
  echo "$c<br>";
}
```